# SAS Proc Mixed model interpretation

Tags: sas, mixed-model

I'm fitting a linear mixed model by SAS.
There are 596 sectors and 8489 subjects. (each sector contains 10~15 subjects).
Each subject is measured at most 6 times, so the total number of observation is 50043.
SAS code are as follows.

```
proc mixed data=work.dat2 covtest method=ml maxfunc=1000 ;
   class group_k sectorid childuid;
   model laz=group_k x1 x2 x4 x6 x1_k x2_k x4_k x6_k 
             / solution cl outpm=out;
         random sectorid;
         repeated / subject=childuid type=cs ;
         run;
```

One of the result tables is as follows. The first table is without the option 'type=cs' (default type=VC), and the second table is with the option 'type=cs'.
[image]
[image]

I don't understand the relation between the SAS result table and the theory presented here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect003.htm

The covariance matrix for the default 'variance component' is $ \sigma_k^2 1(i=j) $ and that for the type 'compound symmetry' is $ \sigma_1 + \sigma^2 1(i=j) $
In the two tables, I don't understand which corresponds to $ \sigma_k, \sigma_1, \sigma $ respectively.

Comment: Was the answer below of any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `random sectorid` stipulates that the variable `sectorid` enters as a random effect ($G$-side of the model). This is the only random effect for the $G$-side ($k=1$). By default, the covariance structure is "Variance Components" (VC). The variance component is given in the row called `SECTORID` in the "Covariance Parameter Estimates" Table. In your first case, then,
$
G = 0.08433 \, I_{596},
$
with $I_{n}$ the identity matrix of dimension $n$.

The statement `repeated / subject=childuid` stipulates that the $R$ matrix, i.e. the covariance matrix of the residuals, is block diagonal with one block for each level of `childuid`. By default, the common covariance structure is "Variance Components" (VC). The corresponding variance component, $\sigma^2$, is given in the row called `Residual` in the "Covariance Parameter Estimates" Table. In your first case, then, each block has a $1.1341$ on the diagonal.

Specifying `type=` in the `repeated` statement changes the common block structure of the $R$ matrix. With `type=cs`, $\sigma^2$ is still in the row called `Residual` and $\sigma^2_1$ is given in the row called `CS`.